# why Hystrix is creating so many threads? and why are waiting threads?

Tags: java, threadpool, hystrix, feign

So, Ive recently ran into a problem with an app, Im using java rx with a feign client (Hystrix) enable to call other services, it works fine (I believe) but at some point (I am investigating why, if is due slow response or too many requests) I get an error that crashes the app...

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@...
```

along a HystrixRuntimeException:

```
FeignClientApi#getMyEndpoint could not be queued for execution
```

This made me think (I might be wrong) Im running out of execution threads, so I investigated the thread on my app and I found this:

[image] [image]

My main question, is this normal? what does it mean the `hystrix-client-api:#` ? is it the number given to the thread? they are all in `WAITING` status with total waited with a value (at the screenshot is a 3)

any idea?

My metric of threads, looks like keeps going up... [image]

the only related configuration here is

feign:
hystrix:
enabled: true

the feign client have a configuration class that the only thing it does is to implement this bean

```
@Bean
public Decoder decoder() { ...//gson decoder  }
```

I also found this after I made multiple requests (and the app dies) checking the process hooked in the app port

[image]

Im using `spring-core-netflix-cloud:1.3.0`

Comment: Sure doesn't look normal to me.  Configuration parameters?

Comment: Added extra information, please take a look